# semilogx histogram with log-spaced bins in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, statistics

Is it possible to make a histogram in PGFPlots on a logarithmic x-axis, with equal-sized (in log space) bins? Just using `semilogxaxis` and `hist` fails as expected. Apparently there is no way to specify the bin edges manually. I could do the log transformation beforehand and adjust the labels, but then I'd lose the logarithmically spaced x minor ticks.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}
    \addplot [fill=gray, samples=200, hist]  table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\ 7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\};
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Looking for equally spaced bins in the log space, rather than what we see below:

[image]

## Update

I can achieve this by pre-transforming and manipulating labels and ticks. I will leave the question open, hoping for a solution that avoids preprocessing and baking in tick mark positions and labels.

```latex
  \begin{axis}[xtick={0,1},xticklabels={$10^0$,$10^1$},minor xtick={0.301,0.477,0.602,0.699,0.778,0.845,0.903,0.954,1.000}]
    % source data: 1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\ 7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
    \addplot [fill=gray, samples=200, hist]  table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {0.00\\ 0.30\\ 0.00\\ 0.70\\ 0.60\\ 1.00\\ 0.85\\ 1.00\\ 0.95\\ 0.90\\ 0.95\\ 0.95\\}; % log10 transform
  \end{axis}
```

[image]